# not able to access pytest mark on module level fixture

Tags: python, scope, pytest, fixtures

I am declaring `pytest.mark` on the test case, and trying to access that in `pytest.fixture`.

**test_my_code.py**

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.mymark("test", "mark")
def test_the_code():
    assert 1 == 1
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def my_fixture(request):
    my_mark = request.node.get_closest_marker("mymark").args
    return
```

When I try to run this code, it gives error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'args'`, but if I remove the `scope="module"` from the `pytest.fixture`, I am able to access that `mark`.

Comment: `request.node` is a module node in the module-scoped fixture, not the test case node. You would get only module-level markers in this fixture, set e.g. via `pytestmark` variable. If you want to get markers of individual tests, the fixture must have the function scope (the default one).

Comment: AFAIR you can get a list of test case nodes from the module node, so you would be able to collect the markers for all tests in the module- if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @hoefling is there any way to declare `@pytest.mark.mymark` as `module` level scope, then I can access with `module` level scope in fixture ?

Comment: Yes, via the `pytestmark` variable. The marker will be applied to all tests in the module then.